# Ensure that calculations are done 64 bits (or at least warn of overflow)

Tags: python, numpy, integer-overflow

I am using python and NumPy. I had the following basic quantity to compute:

```
(QL * (7**k))**2
```

Where

```
QL = 200003
k = 4
```

What puzzled me is that it returned a wrong (negative) number, which doesn't make sense. Then I realised after looking on the internet that the problem was because `k` was a 32-bit numpy integer.

A minimal working example can be the following:

```
QL = 200000
k = np.arange(10)[4]
print((QL * 7**k)**2)
```

This returns `406556672` instead of the correct answer `230592040000000000`. The number is not negative here, but the same problem still occurs.

My question is:

How can I make sure that all the numbers used in my code are of the biggest possible integer size?

I don't want to explicitly specify it for each number that I create.

How can I at least force python to warn me when such things happen?

Comment: Show where the numpy comes in. How do you convert to numpy dtypes to use numpy operators?

Comment: @MadPhysicist numpy only comes in because k has been generated from numpy numbers (it is an element of an np.arange() list). I will add this explanation. I don't get your final sentence. I do not do any conversion here, I just do the computation written with k being a numpy.int32

Comment: Please do post an MCVE. I would like to be able to run a snippet of code that shows the result you claim. Right now, everything is happening in Python, where there are no overflow problems for integers.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added a portion of code that doesn't exactly reproduce the same result (I don't know why), but the same idea (i.e wrong answer) is still here.

Comment: " a wrong (negative) number" Wow! this is a really interesting result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `QL = 200003; k = 4` in Python, the numbers are interpreted as `int`s. By default, if you were to convert these into numpy arrays or scalars, you would end up with whatever the default integer type is on your system.

Here is an example using one-element arrays:

```
QL = np.array([200003])
k = np.array([4])
```

On my system, I find that the `dtype` of both arrays is `int32`. You can change that by selecting your preferred dtype:

```
QL = np.array([200003], dtype=np.int64)
k = np.array([4], dtype=np.int64)
```

If you don't have access to the arrays at creation time, you can always convert them:

```
QL = QL.astype(np.int64)
k = k.astype(int64)
```

An option that is worth considering for integer math is skipping numpy altogether and using Python's infinite precision integers. If one of the numbers is a numpy scalar or one-element array, you can retrieve the corresponding Python object using the [`item`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method:

```
QL = QL.item()
k = k.item()
```

Numpy should raise at least a warning for overflow, but apparently this fails for some operations: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987

**TL;DR**

In your case, `k` is a numpy scalar of type `int32`. You can do either one of the following:

For a numpy 64-bit result:

```
k = np.int64(k)
```

For an infinite-precision Python result:

```
k = k.item()
```

If you don't want to cast each `k` explicitly, you can create the range using the correct type:

```
k = np.arange(10, dtype=np.int64)[4]
```

There is no reliable way to set the default integer type for all new arrays without specifying it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way that python returns me some warning when such "errors" occur ? Also, is there a way to specify python and numpy to **always** work with 64 bits ? I don't want each time I create a variable to have to explicitly say it.

Comment: Also, it is possible that my number will be bigger than 2^64. How to avoid any problem in this case as well ? The biggest number I would have would be around 10^40 to give you an idea (so it is big, but I think still numerically tracktable)

Comment: @StarBucK. I don't know about changing the default type, since that mostly has to do with your platform and the compiler that was used. My naive attempt at setting `np.int_ = np.int64` did not work (as expected :) ). I'll see about the warning.

Comment: @StarBucK. Use Python integers in that case, as they are literally infinite precision. Or try to rewrite your formula to avoid overflow (if possible, but probably not). Perhaps your system supports something like `np.int128`?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Just to understand (I read the documention but it is not totally clear for me). When you do k.item(), it converts the object into a "Standard Python scalar object". Those object have "infinite" accuracy ? It will necesseraly be finite at some point but let's say in practice for number less than 10^60 I shouldn't have a problem ? Is that the meaning of your code ?

Comment: @StarBucK. Yes. Python integers are limited literally only by available memory. 10^60 requires about 200 bits, which is just 25 bytes or so for the data. This will be slower than operating on native types that are suited for your processor architecture, but I doubt you will notice it much.